# Brand New MacBook Pro Retina Glitches

Tags: macbook-pro, display, graphics

I noticed a lot of people have a similar problem like me. Strange glitches in some programs on some controls. They appear totally random. The image shows only one program. It also appears in Safari, iMessage, XCode, Ecliplse. I've absolutely no Idea what could be the reason. Also Apple support doesn't have an answer yet. They told me to observe the problem.

[image: MBPretina graphics issues]

It's the new MacBook Pro Retina 16 GB RAM and 2,6 GHz Model. 1 Week old. Mountain Lion 10.8.2

**Edit**
Some People write that their issue came from a Ram upgrade. And the Ram clock speed was wrong. Here not possible, unopened Laptop.

**Edit 2**
Still observing the problem. Apple told me to use an other "Admin" account (They told me it's important to be an admin account) on the machine. No glitches yet. I'll update the question after some days using the second account.

Comment: I have the same issue and it occurs regardless of integrated or discrete graphics. It appears to go away once I connect an external display. Edit: I should add that it only happens in Messages.app

Comment: I'll second that there are some bugs with Mail and Messages where content isn't drawn correctly - the best thing to do in this case is open a support case, email/upload the pictures and help to establish what and how to get the corruption to arrive. Once engineering can reproduce the issue, a fix usually is quick to arrive from Apple in an update.

Comment: Well that's the thing. I still can't find a pattern to reproduce this. I have 3 other (older) MacBooks all running Mountain Lion. Can't reproduce the error on those. I can't even tell, when the glitches appear and when not. Feel's really randomly.

Answer (score 1):

Did you migrate an account from an old machine? It doesn't look like a hardware problem, but it could be corrupt preferences. Bad video cards will corrupt the whole screen, not have it confined to a single window like your screen shot shows.

Try moving the preferences for Messages.app from your ~/Library/Preferences folder to the desktop. You will have to re-configure messages, but you can always put your old prefs file back.  If that works then you probably have a corrupt Messages prefs file. Try that for each app to see if it helps.

Comment: It's not migrated. New Account created. We already deleted the Finder preferences, which also caused very strange behavior. When we closed a program with CMD + Q it did't switch to the Finder. Focus on "No Program". I'll give it a try.

Comment: I would take it to a genius at an Apple store. They have diagnostic tools that are not available to anybody else.